# ASP.NET MVC4 and Kendo UI "filter": return JSON from Object type

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am using a MVC4 controller to read, on the server, a .json file which contains (among other stuff) declarations of filter conditions to use on Kendo UI datasource.

I would like to load it into an Object, and the to send it to the client through a JsonResult.

This is the json portion i would like to send:

```
{
    activate: {
        logic: "or",
        filters: [
            { field: "fieldA", operator: "eq", value: 100 },
            {
                logic: "and",
                filters: [
                    { field: "fieldA", operator: "lt", value: 100 },
                    { field: "fieldB", operator: "eq", value: true }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I defined a Class to map my json data:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public Object activate { get; set; }
}
```

As a type I use Object, because the value contained there may vary, it is not a recursive structure or contains reserved words as "operator".

I then read the json through:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
ItemModel i = serializer.Deserialize<ItemModel>(new JsonTextReader(reader));
```

At this point, due to the fact I defined "Object" as the type for "activate" json object, I found in my variable an object which refers, as its base, to "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer", which, passing to "Json(i)", result on client as something like "[[[]], [[[[[]], [[]], [[]]], [[[]]".

Is it possible to return to the client the real json data instead of the serialization of the "Object" object (or the equivalent which Json() parser get in trouble with)?
How?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found so far is to use "JsonConvert.SerializeObject" on the returned object:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
ItemModel i = serializer.Deserialize<ItemModel>(new JsonTextReader(reader));
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```